# How Can I create a generic HashMap to insert collections and objects?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, java-6, java-5

How Can I  instantiate  a HashMap to put collections and objects?.

```
//it's wrong
Map<String,?>params=new HashMap<String,? >
List<Person> lstperson=getPerson();
params.put("person",lstperson);
params.put("doc",objectDoc);
params.put("idSol",new Long(5));
service.method(params);

//method

public void method(Map<String, ?> params);
```

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard as a type argument.

Comment: use `Map<String,Object>`

Comment: FWIW, this seems like a bad code smell: it looks like you ought to be storing this data in a class, not an untyped `Map`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Declare the hash map as

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

You can keep the declaration of

```
public void method(Map<String, ?> params);
```

as it is, as long as the method only every tries to read from the map.

Comment: After creating a hashmap like this, how can I add an object of generic type to the hashmap?

Answer (score 6):

All classes in Java extends Object. so you can use Object for a value type in a map, like

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change

```
Map<String,?>params=new HashMap<String,? >
```

to like this

```
Map<String,Object>params=new HashMap<String,Object>()
```

But its not good practice to put all type of objects into single map. Better you can create POJO and add it to map.

Comment: It seems like the map itself should be a POJO instead.

Answer (score 0):

I cam here for substitute in Kotlin

You can declare in kotlin as :-

```
val map: Map<String, Any?>
```